# NaN hr NaN min NaN sec error in Mozilla Firefox version less than 45

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, nan

I am trying to show time in the format hr:min:sec from my database using Angular js but getting error NaN hr NaN min NaN in Mozilla and Safari while its working fine in Chrome. Here is my code:

```
$scope.initTimer = function (id, starttime, endtime) {
    $scope.data.push({"id": id, "starttime": starttime, "endtime": endtime});
    $scope.now = new Date(endtime).getTime();
    $scope.callTimer($scope.data);
};
$scope.callTimer = function (data) {
    angular.forEach(data, function (value) {
        $scope.enquirytime = new Date(value.starttime).getTime();
        $scope.distance = ($scope.enquirytime + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) - $scope.now;
        $scope.days = Math.floor($scope.distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        $scope.hours = Math.floor(($scope.distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        $scope.minutes = Math.floor(($scope.distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        $scope.seconds = Math.floor(($scope.distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        $scope.showtime[value.id] = $scope.hours + " hr " + $scope.minutes + " min " + $scope.seconds + " sec ";
        if ($scope.distance < 0) {
            $scope.hideenquiry[value.id] = true;
        }
    });
    $scope.now = $scope.now + 1000;

};
```

Comment: Why you are taking trouble?.. Just use Datefilter https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer after some research. Find it below:

```
var starttime = starttime;
    var endtime = endtime;
    if (starttime.indexOf('Z') == -1 && endtime.indexOf('Z')) {
        starttime = starttime.replace(' ', 'T') + 'Z';
        endtime = endtime.replace(' ', 'T') + 'Z';
    }
```